Why is my boolean status not resetting after Subscribe method?
I have a simple Submit button and have Mat-Spinner to show the progress. After the call either its Success or Error, my isLoading is not setting to False, because of which my spinner is showing always. I think i am missing something in Angular 18, the Standalone component. Please help
Here is the below code
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormGroupDirective,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../material-module';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  providers: [FormGroupDirective],
  selector: 'app-basic',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './basic.component.html',
  styleUrl: './basic.component.css',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class BasicComponent {
  basicInfo: FormGroup;
  isLoading: boolean;
  errorMsg: string;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public router: Router,
    private apiSvc: ApiService,
  ) {}

Submit Button Code
submit() {

    if (this.basicInfo.valid) {
      this.isLoading = true;

      this.apiSvc.create(this.basicInfo.value).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
      });
    }
  }


<button
  mat-flat-button
  [disabled]="!basicInfo.valid"
  class="custom-width-button"
>
<mat-spinner
  [diameter]="24"
  class="white-spinner"
  *ngIf="isLoading"
></mat-spinner>
</button>


Is your component onPush ? You might need to force change detection.

sorry, i am new to Angular, can you please guide me with the code

@SamK please share more code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

@Naren, form has 3 controls and Submit button, on click of Submit, i have provided a code and the Submit button code also provided

@SamK Could you share the code above export class ComponentName{} the @Component decorator

@SamK Please have a look at this on how to properly format a question for stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
A lot of people like to use stackblitz to illustrate their issue.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

@Naren, added more code

got it.. i removed the code   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
and it worked :)

With onPush, you would need to import ChangeDetectorRef from @angular/core and provide it via dependency injection in your component's constructor. In your subscription, you would need to call markForCheck() which will then trigger change detection. Otherwise onPush will only run change detection when @Input references change.

@SamK instead of removing, just inject the changeDetectorRef and do the markforcheck after assining the loading variable

Can someone please provide me sample code

@NarenMurali Will do,

If your component is using OnPush, you might need to manually trigger change detection.
For example:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: ``,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})

This can be manually called by referencing changeDetectorRef from your components constructor.
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

And then later used in your code..
this.ref.detectChanges();


Checks this view and its children. Use in combination with ChangeDetectorRef#detach to implement local change detection checks.

Or
this.ref.markForCheck();


When a view uses the ChangeDetectionStrategy#OnPush (checkOnce) change detection strategy, explicitly marks the view as changed so that it can be checked again.

Give this a try in your code,
 this.apiSvc.create(this.basicInfo.value).subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.ref.markForCheck();
    },
    error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.ref.markForCheck();
    }
  });

https://v17.angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy 
https://v17.angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Thank you, @khollenbeck. What if i just remove the code changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. Will it affect anything else?

@SamK, I would recommend using OnPush wherever possible. This will prevent Angular from implicitly running change detection cycles. Which will help with performance.

Got it, thank you Khollenbeck

So what happened here was that since the component's change detection strategy is set to push, even though the isLoading's value is updated in the TS file, it is not detected since although it is fire an event, isLoading's value is updated inside a successful completion of a Promise. When comes to the onPush change detection strategy that change is not detect by the change detection, since angular does not know at which time that this would be completed. And here that is happened inside a manual subscription. To understand this you can have a look on this documentation.
So based on the scenario that you need to have, if you need to keep the onPush further, you can convert this isloading into an observable, and emit the new value to it inside the request completion and get that value using an async pipe in the template file.
